# Assign a active class to Clicked button created using For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating dynamic buttons using javascript. But I am unable to assign `<li class="active">` to button onClick. I tried to assign active class using jquery but didnt work so far.As I cant apply Operations of event handling using ID Any good solution using javascript or jquery ? I tried almost as possible soloution given on Stack overflow but didn't work for me.

```
for (var i = 0; i <feature_layer.length ; i++) {
<ul class="nav nav-pills"><a data-toggle="pill" class="mybtn"  style="margin:25px;"  id=' + mapport.selected_feature_layer[i] + '>' + layer_names[i] + '</a></li></ul>';
}
$('.mybtn').click(function() {
    var selected_id =$(this).attr('id');

});
```

Comment: You cannot simply mix JS and HTML in a for loop like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button is created dynamically, you will have to use event delegation.

```
$('body').on("click",".myBtn", function(e){
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Here is the code in action:

```js
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = 'this is a button';
btn.className = 'myBtn';
document.body.appendChild(btn);

$('body').on("click",".myBtn", function(e){
  $(this).addClass("active").text("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: then how can I assign it a active class in this scenario ?

Comment: thank you. It was a small trick  '$('body').' that worked for me.